# How to make appointed row in ListView focused

Tags: c#

Now I am using ListView in a WinForm application. The appliation will read records from the database and show it in ListView. There are maybe 100 rows sorted by some principle in the listview. Now if I want to make 36th row selected(the whole row will be in blue color), I have to scroll the bar and find the row and make it selected. How can I make it auto selected when the form is shown? Is there any method to make the listview scroll to appointed line? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `EnsureVisible`. Sample code for `listView1`:

```
listView1.Items[36].Selected = true;
listView1.EnsureVisible(36);
```

This shows the given row at the bottom. If you want to show it at a higher position (and it is not the last one), you would have to use `EnsureVisible` with one of the following rows (37, 38...).

Comment: Thank you for your infomation, which is useful.

Comment: @robinsun you are welcome. But what you mean with useful information? Is not this the solution to the question you asked?

Comment: I learned a new method EnsureVisible from your information. As for my problem, in the soluntion I found a sealed mehtod which waw created by former developer. So I just used it. But I learned something from you.

Comment: @robinsun All clear. I am here to help. Thanks for the award.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it explicitly:

```
listView1.Items[36].Selected = true;
```

or do it by looping to select multiple elements:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items) { 

        if(item.Text == "aaaaa"){ // or something else

            item.Selected = true;

        }           

    }
```

Comment: This code does not deliver what the OP is asking. He is not worried about selecting a row, but about SHOWING the selected row.

Comment: PS: you have to exit the loop (break) inside the condition; otherwise, it would continue searching even after finding a match. Or you can rely on a different type of loop to avoid the break (e.g., a While loop where the condition is given by the ListViewItem being different to the target value).